# Iterating through HashSet empties HashMap entry

Tags: java, tomcat

The following method gets a "Route" (class name and class method):

```
public Route getRoute(final String method, final String request) {
    if (hasRoutes) {
        for (Map.Entry<Pattern, HashMap<String, String>> entry : routes) {
            Matcher match = entry.getKey().matcher(request);

            if (match.find()) {
                HashMap<String, String> methods = entry.getValue();

                // ISSUE: Returns FALSE after 1st call of Router.getRoute()
                if (methods.containsKey(method)) {
                    return new Route(match.group("interface"), "TRUE (" + method + " - " + match.group("interface") + "): " + methods.get(method));
                } else {
                    return new Route(match.group("interface"), "FALSE (" + method + " - " + match.group("interface") + "): " + methods.values().toString() + ", SIZE: " + entry.getValue().size());
                }

                //return entry.getValue().containsKey(method) ? new Route(match.group("interface"), entry.getValue().get(method)) : null;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

"routes" is defined as:

```
private Set<Entry<Pattern, HashMap<String, String>>> routes;
```

It is a cached representation of a JSON configuration file that defines supported routes, e.g.:

```
{
    "^/?(?<interface>threads)/?$": {
        "GET": "list",
        "POST": "create"
    },
    "^/?(?<interface>threads)/(?<id>\\d+)/?$": {
        "GET": "get",
        "POST": "reply",
        "PUT": "edit",
        "PATCH": "edit",
        "DELETE": "delete"
    }
}
```

EDIT, here's how "routes" is filled from the contents of the JSON file:

```
    try {
        JsonParser parser = JSONFactory.createJsonParser(in);
        JsonNode root = JSONMapper.readTree(parser);
        Iterator base = root.getFieldNames();
        Iterator node;
        String match, method;
        HashMap<Pattern, HashMap<String, String>> routesMap = new HashMap();

        while (base.hasNext()) {
            match = base.next().toString();

            if (match != null) {
                node = root.get(match).getFieldNames();
                HashMap<String, String> methods = new HashMap();

                while (node.hasNext()) {
                    method = node.next().toString();

                    if (method != null) {
                        methods.put(method, root.get(match).get(method).getTextValue());
                    }
                }

                if (!methods.isEmpty()) {
                    routesMap.put(Pattern.compile(match), methods);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!routesMap.isEmpty()) {
            hasRoutes = true;
            routes = routesMap.entrySet();
        }

        // Help garbage collection
        parser = null;
        root = null;
        base = null;
        node = null;
        match = null;
        method = null;
        routesMap = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

EDIT 2, properties in question & init() method:

```
public final static JsonFactory JSONFactory = new JsonFactory();
public final static ObjectMapper JSONMapper = new ObjectMapper();
public static Router router;
private final Class self = getClass();
private final ClassLoader loader = self.getClassLoader();

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    router = new Router(self.getResourceAsStream("/v1_0/Routes.json"), JSONFactory, JSONMapper);
}
```

For some reason when accessing the servlet after the first time the HashMap is empty of values. A x.size() returns zero.

This is a rewrite of a PHP application from the ground up so I apologise in advance if the issue is something mundane.

Full source:
 - [Router source](http://martingallagher.com/code/Router.java)
 - [Route source](http://martingallagher.com/code/Route.java)

Comment: How is it set/cached/etc? Nothing in the code removes anything.

Comment: @Dave Newton, Added the procedure to "cache" a representation of the JSON file in the HashSet.

Comment: What I couldn't find here is, where and how you are caching? Is it cached in servlet init() phase and being used in subsequent phases?

Comment: @thinksteep Added "EDIT 2" which contains the init() method.

Comment: This is what I feel, your inputstream is not closed at the end (unless I missed some code), I think on subsequent calls same stream is being used which returns empty string. Give it try. I may be wrong too.

Comment: @thinksteep Setting the parser to null I _think_ (I'm not Java expert) closes all attached resources. To be on the safe side I have just tested the use of an explicit in.close() and the issue sadly remains.

Comment: @MartinGallagher Setting something to "null" doesn't close open resources. A resource held by the referenced object *may* eventually be closed, but resources should be closed by calling `close` (or whatever the resource type's equivalent is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getOptions()` method removes every entry from this map as it iterates. So, after calling `getOptions()` once, the map is empty.

By the way, assigning `null` to variables does *not* "help the garbage collector." The garbage collector knows that when the scope of a variable is exited, that variable no longer references the object. You are actually slowing things down by assigning values (`null`) that can never be read (as well as cluttering your code with counterproductive noise). A good static analysis tool like FindBugs will warn you that this is bad code.

Comment: You're an hero buddy, amateurish bug, but I'm happy to squash it. Thanks for the tips on garbage collection too.

Answer (score 0):

> Iterating through HashSet empties HashMap entry

That doesn't happen.  Simply iterating a HashSet has no side-effects on the set's contents.

There is something else going on here that is causing your problem.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the code for the Router and Route class in its entirety:

[link](http://martingallagher.com/code/Router.java)
[link](http://martingallagher.com/code/Route.java)